# DB Grid and Editor in Telerik component

Tags: c#

how can i link dbgrid and editor for show text data when selecting row in grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use popup form edit and put Rad Editor on that popup form, like shown here:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/popupeditform/defaultcs.aspx

or you can have external form like shown here :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/dynamicajaxsettings/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid